# How To update JSP/JS in jboss EAP -6.2 without restarting or redeploying build

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am looking for a way so that I can update My Javascript/JSP in my Jboss EAP server. I know alternative for JS. I can update directly in temp folder. But Is there any way for JSP.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

To update JSP pages at runtime you have to enable development-mode in web system,like as:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
<configuration>
    <jsp-configuration development="true"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. but It is redeploying whole build again. Is it normal behaviour?